# Vue.js component method on creation

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm new to Vue and I'd like to make an AJAX call every time my component is rendered.
I have a vue component lets say "test-table" and Id like to fetch the contents via an AJAX call. There are many such tables and I track the active one via an v-if/v-else-if etc.

Currently I have a cheaty solution: in the template for the component I call a computed property called getData via 
 `{{ getData }}` 
 which initiates the Ajax call but does only return an empty string. Id like to switch to the proper way but dont know how.

My code is like so: (its typescript)

```
Vue.component("test-table", {
        props: ["request"],
        data () {
            return {
                tableData: [] as Array<TableClass>,
            }
        },
        template: `{{ getData() }} DO SOME STUFF WITH tableData...`,
        computed: {
            getData() : string {
                get("./foo.php", this.request, true).then(
                    data => this.tableData = data.map(element => new TableClass(data))
                )
                return "";
            }
        }
}
```

HTML:

```
<test-table v-if="testcounter === 1" :request="stuff...">
<test-table v-else-if="testcounter === 2" :request="other stuff...">
...
```

get is an async method that just sends a GET request with request data to the server. The last parameter is only for saying the method to expect a JSON as answer. Similar to JQuerys getJSON method.

the "created" method does NOT work! It fires only one time when the component is first created. If I deactivate and activate again (with v-if) the method is not called again.

Btw: I'm using Vue 2.6.13

Comment: `watch` request, then fire getData, which should be a method not a computed prop

Comment: Wow, this could actually work. Why didn't u write an answer? Also do you know why they've downvoted my question? Isn't it specific enough or...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lifecycle hooks won't fire every time if the component is cached, keep-alive etc

Add a console.log in each of the lifecycle hooks to see.

Change to use a `watcher` which handles firing getData again if request changes.

```
  ...
  watch: {
    request: {
      handler: function() {
        this.getData()
      },
      deep: true
    }
  },
  created() {
     this.getData()
  },
  methods: {
    getData(): string {
      // do request
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the `mounted` hook if your component is continuously rendered/unrendered using `v-if`, like so:

```js
export default {
    mounted() {
        // do ajax call here
        this.callAMethod();
    },
    ...
}
```

Alternatively, you could use the `created()` hook but it is executed earlier in the chain, so this means the DOM template is not created yet so you cant refer to it. `mounted` usually is the way to go.

More info on these hooks can be found [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Instance-Lifecycle-Hooks).

Comment: Tried it, doesn't work. The mounted method is only called once the APP gets mounted. At least in my case. This doesn't server any purpose since it has to be updated constantly. But thx anyway

Comment: You probably have to assign a `key="someidentifier"` onto that `test-table` component such that it does not get re-used, which I believe is what's happening. Then, whenever the `v-if` triggers it to be shown, the component should trigger `mounted` again. But there are other roads towards a good solution.

Answer (score 0):

@FlorianBecker try the lifecycle hook `updated()`. It may be a better fit for what you're trying to achieve. Docs [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#updated).

Comment: This doesn't work since updated is only called, when a watched property changes and my properties only change on the Ajax call receive. Also it would be an infinite loop since every time the Ajax call comes back an update would be triggered cause it edited the property leading to an update which calles another Ajax call and so on and so forth